# Expanded vote scores get closed on live update

Tags: feature-request, bug, vote-count, live-refresh

When looking at the +/- scores for a post, it gets automatically closed when the score live updates.

Normally I guess this wouldn't be too big of a problem, but for questions such as [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/137543/is-stack-overflow-down) and answers like [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/137561/176080) (admittedly where we were playing with making the numbers spin) I'm pretty sure I got RSI from clicking the same place so often just for it to stay open long enough to be meaningful.

Don't know if this is a bug or just a limitation of the live-refresh system (please delete tags as appropriate) but it really was quite irritating!

<del>*N.b. because of the ... unusual... voting that was happening on Jeff's answer, I'm assuming that it was just closing the box on a new vote.  It **could** have actually been when votes were undone (un-downvote in particular), however, I can't be sure*.</del>

^^Having just painstakingly watched the net vote counts on this question, it's definitely on all votes.

Could the live refresh be tweaked to cope with showing net upvote/downvote scores on a post as they come in rather than closing the box to see the total score again?

[image: Image of expanded net score accounting]